# Rscript install packages: how to make it fail with an error code?

Tags: r, docker, tidyverse, cran

I'm building docker containers with R, with lines like:

```
RUN Rscript -e 'install.packages("tidyverse", "text2vec")'
```

However, if there are failures installing one of the packages, even thought there is "...had non-zero exit status" logged, the docker build just carries on.

How can I make Rscript fail with an error code if `install.packages` had an error installing one of its packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen [install2.r](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/littler/blob/master/inst/examples/install2.r) and its `--error` option?

We use it (and wrote it/added that options) for some of the Dockerfiles in the [Rocker Project](https://www.rocker-project.org/) dedicated to Docker support for R.